# How to prove that a set is universe of a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I'm trying to solve this proposition: Let $ \langle A, \cdot, ^{-1}, 1\rangle $ and $ \langle B, \cdot, ^{-1}, 1\rangle $ be groups and let $ \alpha \colon A \to B $ be a homomorphism. 
    Then the set $ N \mathrel{\mathop:}= \{ a \in A : \alpha(a) = 1 \} $ is the universe of a subgroup of A.

I've trying to let a $ X \subseteq A $ such that $ X $ is a subgroup of A. After that, I get an element of $ X $, say $ a \in X $ and trying to get $ \alpha(a) = 1 $ through $ a \in A $ and $ 1 \in A, B, X $. But no idea how to continue the demonstration

[Proposition image](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/6/5/bd8ab522a8610b15fbb4a64a42ebf5ad-full.png)

Comment: You don't have to "let $X$ be" anything. You want to show that $N$, which you have defined, is a subgroup. To start, can you show that if two things are in $N$ then so is their product?

Comment: The universe of a subgroup? What is that thing? Everything you wrote is extremely unclear. Do you want to simply show that $N$ (a.k.a. the kernel of $\alpha$) is a subgroup of $A$?

Comment: The proposition says "[...] N is the universe of a subgroup of A", isn't clear for myself too, I'm not allow to edit and put a picture of the proposition, but I'm hosting a image of that and put on the text

Comment: Here's my best guess regarding the usage of terminology *universe*, based on the notation "$<A, \cdot, ^{-1}, 1\ > $" of the exercise. That notation hints to me that in the context of this exercise a group is required to be expressed very formally as a 4-tuple. Even a subgroup is required to be a 4-tuple. The 4th entry of that 4-tuple is the identity, the third element is the inversion operator, the second element is the group operation, and the first element is the "universe" of the group; the terminology that I've heard more commonly would be the "underlying set" of the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to define a set $X$. Instead, what you need to show is that:

1. The restriction of $\cdot$ to $N\times N$ is a binary operation on $N$;
2. The restriction of ${}^{-1}$ to $N$ is a unary operation on $N$;
3. The co-restriction of $1$ to $N$ is still well-defined (that is, the image lies in $N$;
4. The group identities are satisfied when all operations are restricted as above.

(4 may be moot, or trivial). Once you do that, you will have that $\langle N, \cdot|_{N\times N},{}^{-1}|_N,1\rangle$ is a group (hence $N$ is the universe/underlying set of a group), and since $N\subseteq A$ by construction, it is in fact a subgroup of $\langle A,\cdot,{}^{-1},1\rangle$.